# is it possible get location when a iphone app is not working background

Tags: iphone, ios

Foursquare iphone  app get my location and send me notification even if it is not working background.How can it be?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation of the method [`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW43) of the class [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html). It says:

> If you start this service and your application is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into the background if a new event arrives.

That means that the app will get the notification even if it was terminated.